# Removing database values from a listview with long click listener code isn't working || What can be the problem?

Tags: firebase, android-studio, listview, firebase-realtime-database

This is the code I used in order to remove values from the database

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_post);

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
        this.retriveData();

        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Triggered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Post p = posts.get(position);
                DatabaseReference currentDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts/" + p.key);
                currentDatabase.removeValue().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess");

                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "onFailure");
                    }
                });

                return  true;
            }
        });


    }

    public void retriveData ()
    {
        database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                posts = new ArrayList<Post>();
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    Post p = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
                    posts.add(p);
                    listView.setAdapter(allPostAdapter);

                }

                allPostAdapter = new AllPostAdapter(AllPostActivity.this,0,0, posts);
                listView.setAdapter(allPostAdapter);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

[This is how the list looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiR4o.png) so you need to click long on one of the two items and it was supposed to be deleted.

I noticed I have a little arrow on each item which I do not use and I don't know what it meant for > [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eT7kp.png)

This is what the logcat shows after I long click on one of the items

`2021-04-22 14:40:44.826 10869-10919/com.example.recyclub V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service`

Comment: Please paste the logs in your Logcat in your question.

Comment: That's not really helpful tbh. Can you please try adding a successListerner and a failureListener to the `.remove()` and log the responses? That way me might be able to find accurate reason.

Comment: I added onFailure and onSuccess and also added it to the question so yo ucan see the code of it. Still shows the same logcat of inactivity disconnecting.

Comment: It's hard to debug without logcat, can you please reinstall the app in your emulator/phone, and add `Log.d()` or a `Toast` statements inside your longClick listener to make sure it's getting triggered?

Comment: I used your advice and added the Toast thing so everytime i longclick the item it will show me a toast "Triggered", and it seems like the long click listener isn't even functioning. I also added the toast code in the question post.

Comment: Okay so the problem seems to be with the Recycler View, please add complete code so we can investigate further

Comment: I believe you meant my listview :) And I added it to the question above, if you want to see the adapter too I'd put it in too just let me know.

Comment: I just edited my post XML file to be without this         style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"

This was the answer!

Answer (score 1):

So because the item XML file was like this

```
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Post"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"

        ></TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

It added this strange arrow which was suppose to open up the item and give us more data about it > [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eT7kp.png)

So the long click listener didn't react due to this style edit. So I removed it and now it looks like this.

```
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Post"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        ></TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The item is now loooking like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLb7I.png)  without the little expanding arrow on the side. This was the problem and it is now solved and working well.